# Export GnuRadio datas to create a webSDR

Tags: python, html5-audio, gnuradio

I am an intern and I work on a project to create WebSDR. I need to create a web interface that allows users to observe the activity on the frequency range they want (with a waterfall graph) and also transmit the sound on the chosen frequency.

[example of a websdr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBBaG.png)

For this purpose we have an SDR connected to a local server and running GNURadio. (I show you the block diagram as it is now, it is obviously not final)

[global architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrAH2.png)

I then created a server code in python which retrieves the data sent in UDP via the "UDP Sink" block which for the moment simply transmits it in text to the client code in javascript to display it on an html page. (I will send you the codes if needed)

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blDvm.png)

[client.js and client.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ajf.png)

I'm stuck now, I can't find any resources on the internet for the rest. I would like to process the data on the server in order to create an audio data stream that would be streamed to the web client. But also a way to create a waterfall graphic, which I will convert to an image afterwards and which will be sent to the client every second to give the impression that the waterfall graphic is refreshed regularly.

Please can you give me some answers to create these two features. I am open to other proposals as well if the method I want to apply is not the right one.

Thank you very much,

Comment: I'm going to stop you right there: you seem to be using GNU Radio 3.7, and that's end-of-life. It's especially lacking in network and data serialization functionality. Don't do that to yourself. The GNU Radio community also has less experience to help you if you use a dead version. Update to GNU Radio 3.10.

Comment: also, please don't post pictures of code, but simply *code*. There's a code formatting button `{}`.

Comment: Fun fact, by the way, is that this has been done before, for example as the `bokeh gui` option (which does not exist in GNU Radio 3.7. Another reason to upgrade).